# django save(commit=False) versus full_clean

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project and creating many model instances from batch upload form. I am creating many unsaved model instances in order to test them for errors as I don't want to enter any instances until the user has submitted a full set of valid records to avoid unintentional duplications within the database. My question is whether there is a good reason to use either `save(commit=False)` or `full_clean` on the unsaved model instances. I am currently using `full_clean`, but not sure what the differences/benefits are of one versus the other.

Comment: Realized that the `commit=False` option is only available for a `ModelForm` and not a model. Are there other options for validating a model before saving aside from `full_clean` now that I realize that `commit=False` is not an option?

Comment: You could always just override the model's save and error out before invoking the super...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `full_clean()` is the correct way to validate a model instance.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

try:
    obj.full_clean()
except ValidationError:
    # handle invalid object
```

When dealing with a model form, calling `is_valid()` will perform the model validation, so you don't have to call `full_clean()` manually.

Calling `save()` with `commit=False` doesn't perform model validation. Instead, it gives you the opportunity to change the object before you save it to the database. A common example is to set the user attribute to the user that is currently logged on.